# two-point concentrated load

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, dirac-delta

I am trying to solve the following problem with two point load:

$$
\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} = \delta(x-1/4) - \delta(x-3/4)
$$
With boundary conditions $u'(0) = 0$ and where $u'(1) = 0$

From the definition, we can say that:

$$
 u(x) =
  \begin{cases} 
      \hfill ax+b    \hfill & 0 \leq x < 1/4 \\
      \hfill c(x- \frac{1}{4}) +d   \hfill & 1/4 < x < 3/4 \\
      \hfill e(x- \frac{3}{4}) +g   \hfill & 3/4 < x \leq 1 
  \end{cases}
$$

How do I go from here to find *all solutions* to the problem?

Comment: I assume you are looking for a weak solution in $C(0,1)$.  Try to determine what values of the constants $a, \dots, g$ will satisfy the boundary conditions and provide continuity at $x = 1/4, 3/4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can really work out the solution to the problem by just thinking of moving left to right. You start out at $u_0$, and are constant until the first jump at $1/4$. Then the slope is $1$, and stays that way until the second jump at $3/4$. Then the slope is $0$ again, and stays that way. These slopes are consistent with the boundary conditions. Putting what I've said into symbols and taking into account the continuity requirement, you get

$$u(x) = \begin{cases} 
u_0 & x \in [0,1/4) \\
(x-1/4) + u_0 & x \in [1/4,3/4) \\
1/2 + u_0 & x \in [3/4,1]\end{cases}.$$

Note that $u_0$ is a free parameter, as should be expected with a pure Neumann boundary condition.

Comment: How did you get the $1/2+u_0$ for $x \in [3/4,1]$ ? and what do you mean by free parameter in this case?

Comment: @amaatouq The $1/2$ comes to enforce continuity between the second and third pieces. Specifically, if you plug in $3/4$ into the second branch you get $1/2+u_0$. By "free parameter" I mean that it is not specified by the problem; for any real number $u_0$, the function I wrote down will solve the problem as it is currently formulated.

Comment: Integrating across the delta function at $x=\frac 34$ the slope should increase by $1$, not decrease by $1$ as in your solution.  I believe the two boundary conditions are inconsistent as given-there should be a difference of $2$ in the slope from the start to the end.  Having the two boundary conditions redundant corresponds to a single parameter family of solutions, as there should be.

Comment: @RossMillikan There is a minus sign in the differential equation. It does indeed decrease by $1$.

Comment: @Ian:  I missed that.  You are right.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your beam has not broken, $u(x)$ must be continuous.  The only threats to this are at $x=\frac 14, \frac34$.  You can write two equations joining the solutions across those points.  If you integrate $u''(x)$ across one of the delta functions, you should get a step in $u'(x)$ at those points.  You can use that to get two more equations.  Now you have four equations in six unknowns, so have a two parameter family of solutions before you consider the boundary conditions.  The boundary conditions look like they give you two more equations, so there will be a unique solution, but they turn out to be redundant, so you have a one parameter family

Comment: With two constant functions and one linear interpolant $u(0) = u(1) = 0$ would force the solution to be identically zero.  

Shouldn't there be two equations to ensure continuity, two equations to satisfy the BCs and two free variables?  For example, if $u(x)$ is a solution so is $u(x) + const$, so that provides one degree of freedom.  And the value of $c$ provides another.

Comment: The boundary conditions are in terms of $u'$ as the ends are on a moving ring or something (Neumann boundary condition) ... Also, there shouldn't be a unique solution, but rather infinitely many solutions (I think). Would you please show the set of equations?

Comment: With a Neumann condition of this type, the solution is only unique up to an additive constant.

Comment: @Titus:   I missed the minus sign on the second delta function.  Fixed.